# How can we overlap two images using css style?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a list of images in an html table and need to overlap a small icon on each image. How can we do this using z index and positioning?

Comment: read this
may be help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863644/overlap-across-width-of-two-divs

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```css
.under {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.over {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://tafttest.com/184x46.png" width="184" height="46" class="under" />
<img src="https://tafttest.com/100x84.png" width="100" height="84" class="over" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `position:relative` and set `right:30px`, `bottom:30px`, that would shift it up and left by 30 pixels.

CSS:

```
.icon{
position:relative;
right:30px;
bottom:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The element you want to be on top needs to have a higher z-index

So the small icon would have a z-index of 2
and the images would have a z-index of 1

Example:

```
.icon {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
}

.images {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an guide about you can use z-index and here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index

an article about positioning
http://www.tizag.com/cssT/position.php

Comment: That Mozilla page yields a 404. Here's an updated link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index