# How to add an image inside a container without the container moving out of proportion?

Tags: image, containers

I created a shape (a rectangle to be exact) and in this shape I wish to have an image overlapping its actual size (e.g the rectangle would be 400px by 400px and the image would be 600px by 600px).

Are there any ways of doing this? Here's a mockup of what I'm describing:

[image]

EDIT: To achieve this, simply use 
    `z-index: 1;`
    `position: absolute;`

Thanks user acarlon.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are after, but it sounds like you want an image cropped to a container div.

What you want is `overflow: hidden` on the container div. See [here](http://spigotdesign.com/2011/11/crop-any-size-image-with-css/) for details.

You can also use `clip`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip).

**Update**

Actually, it seems like you want one image to overlap another. In which case you want to use absolute positioning and z-index. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1782662/746754).

Comment: @Cwtch22 - glad that it was helpful, please upvote or accept if it was.