# Image in a circle

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following image:

[image]

On my website I want to surround it with a circle like this:

[image]

Question: Is it possible to do this with CSS/how? If yes, which option is better, physically making an image with the circle or using CSS?

Comment: maybe have an image with a transparent background that is the circle - then look here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782601/how-can-we-overlap-two-images-using-css-style

Comment: You can use a `clip-path`

Comment: on my opinion better choice is to crop it manually with Photoshop to avoid across-browsers problems caused by incompatibility of the transparent property

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can create using CSS

#### check this live [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T5X4U/6/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="outbody">
    <img class="img-circle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysyvw.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outbody
{
    width:35%;  
    padding:10px;    
    background-color:#fe0000;
}
.img-circle {
  width: 90%;
  border: 10px solid white;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
            border-radius: 50%;

       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);  
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);  
               box-shadow: 0 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @Jay Patel scenario you can try this out :

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<img class="img-circle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysyvw.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-circle {
  width: 90%;
  border: 10px solid white;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
            border-radius: 50%;

       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,1);  
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,1);  
               box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
#container
{
    background-color:red;
    width:35%;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**Demo :** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mahmoudSarhan/T5X4U/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to inner drop shadow, you can use the `inset` option with the `box-shadow`.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TpmeR/)

**HTML**

```
<div class=circle>
    <div class=image>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
   background : red;
   display    : inline-block;
}

.circle .image {
    margin              : 10px;
    border-radius       : 50%;
    width               : 250px;
    height              : 250px;
    box-shadow          : inset 0 0 30px #000000;
    background-image    : url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysyvw.png);
    background-position : 50%;
}
```