# Is there a way of overlapping 2 images using the coordinates of the bigger image (under the second one) using HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

How do I overlap two or more images using the coordinates of the bigger image, under, to put another smaller image on top?
The coordinates are in relation to the bigger image, not the viewport.
Library suggestions also work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we overlap two images using css style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782601/how-can-we-overlap-two-images-using-css-style)

Comment: There are so many examples here on SO, did you see and try them?  If so, update your answer and describe what you tried, and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `position: absolute;` and just assign coordinates?